# ¿Cómo pasarle al método una variable en JSTL?

Tags: mysql, jsp, mysql-workbench, servlets

Soy nueva JSTL y no sé muy bien como funciona, necesito pasarle al método el email, pero no me deja pasarselo, ¿cómo debería hacerlo? Quiero mostrar los pedidos que haya realizado el cliente.

```
<c:set var="email" value="${cliente.email_cliente}"/>


 <c:forEach var="pedido" begin="0" items="${pedidoCAD.leerPedido(${email})}">
        <h1>Id pedido ${pedido.id_pedido}</h1>
        <h1>Fecha pedido ${pedido.fecha_pedido}</h1>
        <h1>precio pedido ${pedido.precio_total_pedido}</h1>
    </c:forEach>
```

---

Tengo añadido los getter y setter en los beans, los métodos de cada uno los tengo en otra clase.

**Cliente.java**

```
public class Cliente {

Conexion conexion;

int id_cliente;
String email_cliente,
        nombre_cliente,
        apellido1_cliente;

public int getId_cliente() {
    return id_cliente;
}

public void setId_cliente(int id_cliente) {
    this.id_cliente = id_cliente;
}

public String getEmail_cliente() {
    return email_cliente;
}

public void setEmail_cliente(String email_cliente) {
    this.email_cliente = email_cliente;
}

public String getNombre_cliente() {
    return nombre_cliente;
}

public void setNombre_cliente(String nombre_cliente) {
    this.nombre_cliente = nombre_cliente;
}

public String getApellido1_cliente() {
    return apellido1_cliente;
}

public void setApellido1_cliente(String apellido1_cliente) {
    this.apellido1_cliente = apellido1_cliente;
}
```

}

Comment: prueba `${pedidoCAD.leerPedido(email)}` no necesitas abrir otra vez las llaves `${}`

Comment: Ya probé y nada, con las llaves no recoge el valor de la variable. Está correcto llamar así al método?

Comment: @SJuan76 pero en JSTL no me deja... igual estoy haciendo algo mal. Añado el bean.

Comment: Además, por favor explica qué significa "no me deja"... ¿Valor en blanco? ¿Excepción (y cuál)?

Comment: Perdón... el error que me parece  si le paso items="${pedidoCAD.leerPedido(email)}"   es javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NullPointerException, pero si intento pasarle ${email} el propio Netbean me dice 'Encountered "{"

Comment: ¿Seguro que no el error no está en la implementación del método *leerPedido*?

Comment: @SJuan76 Vale  si detecte el error, claro si llamos a _mostrarPedidos()_ que me devuelve un ArrayList si me funciona. Pero si quiero llamar a _leerPedido()_ que me devuelve un objeto, como puedo mostrarlos?

Comment: Depende del tipo de objeto, claro... Si *leerPedido()* te devuelve un *Pedido*, entonces `<c:set var="pedido" value="${pedidoCAD.leerPedido(${email})}"/>` en vez de el *for* sería una opción.

Comment: @SJuan76 Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!